# Force row of images

Tags: html, css, image, row

I'm more of a designer than a coder, so apologies if this question seems bone-headed and the answer obvious.

Anyway, with that caveat out of the way... I'm trying to create a page where the images are in a row that extend off the right edge of the screen, so that the user can scroll to see more images. Other interface elements like the logo and nav are fixed in place.

You can see the page here: http://werewolf.phantomlimb.net/

and the CSS here: http://werewolf.phantomlimb.net/wolf.css

To remove the spaces between the images I have floated them left.

My question is that in order to prevent the images from wrapping, even with a height attribute on the container div and display: block I have to give the div a width value, in this case 4000px. A width of auto for example makes the images wrap onto a new line, which is what I *don't* want!

As I may not always know the exact width of the combined images, is there a width value I can use that will force the images to stay in a single row, or some other CSS trick?

Many thanks.

J

Comment: Please add your code and even better make a js fiddle with your code in it... This will make any answers valuable even if you change the website in the future.

Comment: OK, I guess you mean this... http://jsfiddle.net/cbrp0L6d/

Answer (score 1):

I would use inline-block for this kind of stuff.

Something like this:

```
#imgHolder{
    font-size: 0px; /* Remove the spaces between the images */ 
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent the images from wrapping */
}

#imgHolder img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 654px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/155ukfwp/